# PHP: how to convert this sentence in given format

Tags: php, regex, code-snippets

> "[5|five] [Tips|Suggestions] for an Unforgettable Trip|Five
>   suggestions for a un-regret able Trip|[5|five] [tips|suggestions] for
>   an [amazing|incredible] Trip|Five [tips|suggestions] for an
>   astonishing Trip"

to

> "[5|five] [Tips|Suggestions] for an Unforgettable Trip~Five
>   suggestions for a un-regret able Trip~[5|five] [tips|suggestions] for
>   an [amazing|incredible] Trip~Five [tips|suggestions] for an
>   astonishing Trip"

I could use  `str_replace("|", "~", $code)` but the issue is I don't want to  convert `"|"` into `"~"` if it is between  `"[ ]"`.

Comment: is your sentence is as input of any variable?

Answer (score 4):

```
for($i=0,$s=strlen($str),$c=0;$i<$s;++$i){
    if($str[$i]=='[')++$c;
    elseif($str[$i]==']')--$c;
    elseif(!$c && $str[$i]=='|')$str[$i]='~';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do what you're after `/^(?<!\[.)\|(?!].)/`

Combine with `preg_replace` and klabamo you've got it :)

This now seems to work a lot better!

```
$sentence = "[5|five] [Tips|Suggestions] for an Unforgettable Trip~Five suggestions for a un-regret able Trip~[5|five] [tips|suggestions] for an [amazing|incredible] Trip~Five [tips|suggestions] for an astonishing Trip";

$newSentence = preg_replace("/^(?<!\[.)\|(?!].)/", "~", $sentence);

echo $newSentence;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  Your "before" string is the same as the OP's "after" string; your code doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
$in = "[5|five] [Tips|Suggestions] for an Unforgettable Trip|Five suggestions for a un-regret able Trip|[5|five] [tips|suggestions] for an [amazing|incredible] Trip|Five [tips|suggestions] for an astonishing Trip";
$out = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\])([^\[]*?)\|([^\[]*?)(?=\[|$)/s', '\1~\2', $in);
```

The regular expression works as follows, and will be correct as long as you don't nest brackets (`[foo [bar]]`).

> `(?<=^|\])` - start at the beginning of the string or following a `]`
>   `([^\[]*?)` - capture any number of characters that aren't a `[`
>   `\|` - the character we want to replace
>   `([^\[]*?)` - capture any number of characters that aren't a `[` (again)
>   `(?=\[|$)` - stop matching at the end of the string or before a `[`

Comment: Surely that's a bit of overkill?

Comment: @James I'm tired so I might be missing something, but it seems like your solution won't behave properly for the example, because it can't match an arbitrary number of characters between the `]` and the `|`. This works properly.

Comment: @James: Your regex just does not work in preg_replace, Jeremy's does. To reduce the overhead, in my regex I'm working on the negation.

Comment: I've updated the regex and provided an example. It works for me on this test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace all with str_replace and then re-replace those which are inside `[]` ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/WTXhQ7Qs)):

```
$subject = '[5|five] [Tips|Suggestions] for an Unforgettable Trip|Five suggestions for a 
un-regret able Trip|[5|five] [tips|suggestions] for an [amazing|incredible] Trip|Five [tips|suggestions] for an astonishing Trip';
$result = str_replace('|', '~', $subject);
$pattern = '((\[[^\]]*)~([^\[]*\]))';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$1|$2', $result);

var_dump($subject, $result);
```

Comment: yehh  this one is also working well, thanks man !! rocking !!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the square brackets will always be properly balanced and never nested, a simple lookahead is all you need:

```
$after = preg_replace('/\|(?![^][]*+\])/', '~', $before);
```

**[demo](http://ideone.com/BtB7Q)**

Starting immediately after the pipe character, the lookahead scans for the next right square bracket.  If it finds one without seeing a *left* square bracket first, the pipe must be inside a pair of brackets.  There's no need to check for the opening bracket with a lookbehind, which is good, because PHP (like most regex flavors) doesn't support variable-width lookbehinds.

I used a *negative* lookahead, but a *positive* lookahead could work, too:

```
$after = preg_replace('/\|(?=[^][]*+(?:\[|$))/', '~', $before);
```

**[demo](http://ideone.com/5dwjd)**

Note that it isn't necessary to escape the right square bracket in a character class if it's the first character listed (or, as in this case, the first character after the negating `^`).  Thus, the odd-looking `[^][]` for "not a square bracket".  And `*+` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

If square brackets can be nested, you should forget about regexes and go with [@RiaD's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677838/php-how-to-convert-this-sentence-in-given-format/6677882#6677882).  It might still be possible to use regexes, but it will be a lot more complicated.

Comment: i  just downloaded and tried, it is working really great!! thanks a lot for your kind help.

Answer (score -1):

You could potentially use PHP preg_match and combine with str_replace - I am not a regexp expert so I won't be able to write anything for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php